# Turning on SMS delivery report on Android 9

Tags: sms, huawei

How can I turn on SMS delivery report on Android 9? In messaging section, I go to settings, but there's no "advanced" option. I'm using Huawei Y5 2019.

Here's a screenshot and there's no double-check (which is a sign of a delivered message)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, whether to show delivery reports or not is to be implemented in a messaging app, and is independent of Android version. If you don't see any such option in your stock messaging app, than it doesn't have that functionality. I suggest you try a third-party messaging app from Play Store or F-Droid. It should work out.